# Winform did not show the icon in the taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two programs A and B, when something happened I use the process.start() in A to launch B.  after the B was successfully launched the icon of B did not show in the windows taskbar. But when I click on the window of B, the icon of B will show in the windows taskbar. I Can't figure out the reason.

Here is my code snippet

```
    private void StartProcess()
    {
        string appName = Application.StartupPath + @"\AppB.exe";

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = appName,
        };

        Process process = Process.Start(psi);

    }
```

Comment: Can you show to us at least what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

if B is your coded program then set application icon in Installer. After installation that icon will be displayed in task bar on every launch.

Comment: Yes, if I launch the B by Double click , the icon will show int task bar, But I need to lunch it int a background program A.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ShowInTaskBar = true;
```

and you have to use NotifyIcon

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx